# How did Szmielew prove that Pasch's axiom is a consequence of the circle axiom?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, foundations, axioms

It is [alleged](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237994/pasch-axiom-and-pythagorean-field-condition) that Szmielew proved that Pasch's axiom is a consequence of the circle axiom. The source is said to be

> The Pasch axiom as a consequence of the circle axiom, Bull.Acad.Polon.Sci.Sér.Sci.Math.Astronom.Phys.18 (1970), 751-758

But I don't have a copy of this yet.

Answer (score 4):

No luck here with the source (online issues start at 1973), but I did find the [abstract:](https://zbmath.org/0204.20901)

> The Pasch axiom is known to be independent of the remaining axioms of
> the plane Euclidean geometry $E$. By replacing, in the axiom system of
> $E$, the continuity axiom ($C_0$) by the circle axiom ($C$) one gets
> an axion system for the so called geometry of elementary
> constructions. In this axiom system the Pasch axiom occurs to be
> dependent, thus superfluous. At the first glance the situation seems
> to be paradoxical, since it is common to say that $C$ is a particular
> consequence of $C_0$. Actually in the proof of $C$ besides $C_0$ also
> some other axioms of $E$ are involved, and, as we see now, the Pasch
> axiom must be one of them.

Moreover, Victor Pambuccian haș written an [article](https://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/Maths/PDF2/mathschron018-009.pdf) "in memoriam to Wanda Szmielew", where he describes the axiom system she used in her 1970 paper.